# load page after 5 second without refresh js

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have 2 page loader.php and index.php, 
i want to show page loader.php in index.php then dispear after 5 second from index.php without refresh or redirect ! ps : page not a div,sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Do you want change the content after 5 seconds or ?

Comment: Not getting your question..

Comment: Hendra Nucleo Yes :)

Answer (score 0):

In index.php, include the loader.php content into a `div` that you've styled to be full page and `z-index`ed above the rest. With Javascript, `setTimeout` for 5000 ms to hide the `div`.

*A brief answer for a brief question.*